# Go nested func not allowed

Tags: html, go, render

I want to get the values of one table of my db and parse them in an html. This is the code that I used to try to do it but I got an error called `nested func not allowed`.

I started creating an estructure:

```
type App struct{
    Title string
    Author string
    Description string
}
```

I created a function to render the templates:

```
func render(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string){
    tmpl = fmt.Sprintf("templates/%s", tmpl)
    t, err := template.ParseFiles(tmpl)
    if err != nil{
        log.Print("template parsing error: ", err)
    }
    err = t.Execute(w, "")
    if err != nil{
        log.Print("template executing error: ", err)
    }
}
```

Then, here I got the apps from the database and try to render them to the html.

```
func myApps(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres"," user=postgres dbname=test host=localhost password=1234 sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
        rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT title, author, description FROM apps
                                 WHERE title ILIKE $1
                                 OR author ILIKE $1
                                 OR description ILIKE $1`)
            defer rows.Close()

            apps := []App{}
            for rows.Next(){
                b := App{}
                err := rows.Scan(&b.Title, &b.Author, &b.Description)
                apps = append(apps, b)

    render(w, "myapps.html", apps)
}
```

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some type around the line including a [`for` statement](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements):

```
for rows.Next(){
```

I don't see that opening '`{`' closed anywhere else.

(Or it is closed, but then `func myApps` isn't closed)

Maybe it should be:

```
        for rows.Next() {
            b := App{}
            err := rows.Scan(&b.Title, &b.Author, &b.Description)
            apps = append(apps, b)
        }
        render(w, "myapps.html", apps)
}
```

In any case, running `go fmt` is always a good idea.

Comment: Yeah thanks, thats true!. The problem now is that tell me that "cannot use apps <type []App) as type string in argument to render.

Comment: @devtreat that is a different question. And yes, `render` expects a `tmpl string` as a second argument, so that makes sense.

Comment: What should I do to render correctly the values of apps?. Thank you.

Comment: @devtreat not sure, as I don't know the this kind of rendering, but asking a new question more focused on that would be more efficient.

Comment: Well, then I will have to make a new question about it. Thanks anyways!